# Laravel 4.2 route 404 file not found error -- htaccess error

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes

temporary site is:
http://173.254.74.167/eccaorgn/home

which is not working. but while i add http://173.254.74.167/eccaorgn/index.php/home, it work.
so i want to remove this index.php.
mine htaccess code is:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On
   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://173.254.74.167/~eccaorgn/$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
</IfModule>
```

so tell me guys what to do in this case i try all my best.. but not get any proper solutions.

Comment: thanks guys i got my answer..

Answer (score 0):

i solved my question, giving 644 default folder access